# How do I open a new JFrame and run my game after closing another JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe, minesweeper

I'm making a minesweeper game, and I want the user to be able to pick from beginner, intermediate, and advanced before playing the game. So far what I have is a JFrame that opens when I open the program with buttons for each difficulty.

Here are my main functions and the function to choose the difficulty. I'm wondering how I could still call all the functions in my main function after I call chooseGameDifficulty, because right now they're not being called.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    chooseGameDifficulty();
    game.initGame();
    initBoard();
    getClick();

    while (gameOver == false) {
        showUserTile();
        checkGameWon();
    }
}



  public static void chooseGameDifficulty() {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame chooseDifficulty = new JFrame("Minesweeper");
    chooseDifficulty.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    chooseDifficulty.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    chooseDifficulty.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    JButton B = new JButton("Beginner");
    JButton I = new JButton("Intermediate");
    JButton E = new JButton("Expert");
    chooseDifficulty.add(B);
    chooseDifficulty.add(I);
    chooseDifficulty.add(E);
    B.addMouseListener(
        new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            game.setGameDifficulty("Beginner");
            chooseDifficulty.setVisible(false);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
            }
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
            }
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
            }
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            }
        }
    ); 


    // same thing for the other buttons

    chooseDifficulty.pack();
    chooseDifficulty.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    chooseDifficulty.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Here's one way to arrange your Swing components and your model / view / controller classes, [Minesweeper Applet](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=300).

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not exit on close as default operation on the choose difficulty frame.
2. I will advise you to use JDialog for choose difficulty popoup